# A question on extension of contractive completely positive map

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Assume $A$ is a nonunital C*-algebra, $B$ is a unital C*-algebra and $\phi:A \rightarrow  B$ is a contractive completely map. Then $\phi$ can extend to a unital completely positive map $\bar{\phi}: \bar{A} \rightarrow B$ by the formula
$$\bar{\phi} (a+\lambda1_{\bar{A}})=\phi(a)+\lambda1_{B}$$
where $\bar{A}$ denotes the unitization of $A$.

There are two quotation below:

1. The norm of $\bar{\phi}$ may be larger than that of $\phi$ if and only if $||\phi||<1$. I do not know how to verify, and I think oneside is easy.
2. If we require that $1_{\bar{A}}\longmapsto||\phi||1_{B}$, and this produces a map with the same norm as that of $\phi$? I do not know how to get $||\phi||=||\bar{\phi}||$ here.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the fact that a unital completely contractive map between unital C*-algebras is already completely positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because $\bar\phi$ will be unital and completely contractive, so $\|\bar\phi\|=1$.
2. Because a completely positive map achieves its norm at the identity. So $$ \|\bar\phi\|=\|\bar\phi(1_{\bar A})\|=\|\phi\|.$$